# Condition to be concyclic

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

What condition would you impose upon $n$ points on a plane of which no three points are collinear so that they are
concyclic if the distances of each point from the all remaining points are known? (Here $n>5$ because the required condition for only $4$ points is known )

This seems elementary but very difficult.

Comment: $n\geq 5$ points are concyclic iff any four of them are concyclic, so you can just write down the condition for every quadruple.

Answer (score 5):

Ptolemy's identity seems to answer your question.

Comment: There is a problem with using Ptolemy‘s theorem which can be seen by considering the case where the vertices are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$. Then the corresponding Ptolemy-type relationship holds but with a minus sign. The problem lies in the non-convexity. As far as I can see this confusion is quite widespread in the literature. Sometimes the condition of convexity is stated explicitly, sometimes (but usually not) it is included in the definition of cyclicity and sometimes the problem is ignored. It seems from the way the present problem is

Comment: @pflichtig $2=1+1$ --- where is the "minus sign"?

Comment: In this context to be read as $1=2-1$ (see comment in answer below).

Comment: @terceira still I do not see your point, for me Ptolemy says that if sum of these three product = 2x(largest product) then the quadruple is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for a positive answer.  We note that as has already been pointed out we can reduce to the case of a single quadrilateral $A_1 A_2A_3A_4$ with known side and diagonal lengths.  Now we use the generalised Heron principle.  We can express any quantity associated with a triangle $A_1A_2A_3$ in terms of its side lengths.  This is done using the $p,q$ method—we assume that the vertices are $(0,0)$, $(e_{12},0)$ and $(p,q)$.  It is then an easy exercise to obtain $p$ and $q$ in terms of the side lengths and this establishes the principle—we compute any quantity (e.g. area $\frac 1 2 e_{12} q$) in terms of $p$ and $q$ and so in terms of the side lengths.  We note that there is an ambiguity in the sign of $q$ which then has to be taken into consideration—corresponding to the orientation of the triangle.

Returning to our problem, we note that the circumcentre is $$\left(\frac {e_{12}} 2,- \frac{e_{12}-p^2-q^2}{2 q}\right)$$ and so can be expressed in terms of the side lengths.  We then use the fact that the quadrilateral is cyclic if and only if the circumcentres of $A_1A _2A_3 $ and $A_1 A_2 A_4 $ coincide. We now have all the ingredients required to solve the problem.

Since I can‘t reply to the above comment in the form of a comment, and my descripton seems to have been misunderstood here is the precise statement: points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ in the plane are cyclic (sensu lato) if and only if
$$\pm |AC||BD|\pm|AD||BC|\pm|AB||CD|=0,$$ whereby the choice of signs contains precisely one minus (so that there are three conditions, one of which has to be satisfied).